# Coded Formula 1 Champions

Tags: knowledge, visual, cipher, pattern, sports

- This is a list of some of the  Formula 1 championship winning drivers in their coded form.
- The constructors that helped them to win the championship are also coded in the same row.

---

***COMPLETE THE TABLE***

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drivers and constructors you see are

> 1. M**i**ch**ae**l Sch**u**m**a**ch**e**r - F**e**rr**a**r**i**
> 2. J**a**ck**ie** St**e**w**a**rt - Tyrr**e**ll
> 3. M**a**r**io** **A**ndr**e**tt**i** - L**o**t**u**s.

The fourth row should be completed by

> Driver: **A**yrt**o**n S**e**nn**a** [image]
>  Constructor: McL**a**r**e**n [image]

The fifth row should be completed by

> Driver: J**e**ns**o**n B**u**tt**o**n [image] 
>  Constructor: Br**a**wn GP [image]

Because

> The grid of 5 squares are vowels; a, e, i, o, u (in order). And the red color indicate which vowels that are involved. I used [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_World_Constructors%27_Champions) source to derive to the correct constructor. From there I just looked for vowels that corresponded to a championship drivers name that won with the help of that constructor.